# What directories to/not backup

Tags: backup, directory, rsnapshot, exclude

I'm setting up rsnapshot to backup a production LAMP server. These are the directories that currently are going to be backed up.

- /home
- /etc
- /usr/local
- /root
- /var

What directories can I exclude from `/var`? Anything else that should be backed up/excluded?

Side: Is there a problem backing up to `/var/backups`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably skip `/var/run`, but that directory holds so little data, it's probably not worth skipping.

Sure, you can back up to `/var/backup` (or whatever location you wish, really). Just be careful exclude your `/var/backup` from your backup sets otherwise you'll get into a recursive backup situation, which isn't good.

Additionally, I assume that `/var/backup` is on local disk? If so, make sure to consider how you'll get the contents of `/var/backup` off of local disk to a remote location somehow. Needless to say, those backups won't do you a bit of good on local disk if you have a hard drive failure or filesystem corruption.

Comment: Thanks! The server is in the Rackspace cloud, and is using their backup also. But yes, the local backups will be backed up to another server in that cloud.